# PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(getApplicationCOntext()) inter application access

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences, default

`SharedPreference pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(appcontext);`

Can values saved in these preferences be accessed between different application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153231/android-sharedpreferences-with-mode-private-mode-world-readable-mode-world-writa

Comment: Hi Gabbar, my question is specific to PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference. I want to know, if without defining the pref name and mode , is it possible to share values between different application.

Comment: getDefaultSharedPreference is return SharedPreference with mode private