# Confused for MODES in SharedPreferences : MODE_APPEND

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPrefrences in App to manage login session of user.

For that, I have used MODE_PRIVATE as an argument while initializing instance of SharedPrefrence as below :

```
SharedPrefrence myPref=getSharedPrefrences("MY_PREF",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now, I have read about different MODES used in SharedPrefrences like **MODE_PRIVATE**, **MODE_APPEND**, **WORLD_READABLE** etc..

But, I not get the things clearly. I have used MODE_APPEND in place of MODE_PRIVATE. Getting Same results.

What is the differences and conditions to use them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SharedPreferences with MODE\_PRIVATE,MODE\_WORLD\_READABLE,MODE\_WORLD\_WRITABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153231/android-sharedpreferences-with-mode-private-mode-world-readable-mode-world-writa)

Comment: I want to also know about MODE_APPEND. Its not explained there..

Answer (score 0):

**MODE_APPEND**

This will append the new preferences with the already existing preferences.

**MODE_PRIVATE**

In this mode, the file can only be accessed using the calling application, means the app.

Comment: Give me any example for MODE_APPEND.